# Is there an easy/standard way to add front-end build tools to a Rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, build-automation, frontend

I've been moved onto a Ruby on Rails (2.x) project recently, and I'm attempting to add some build tools which will improve front-end code quality. I'd ideally like to add linting for JavaScript and CSS, as well as a unit testing framework (preferably [Mocha](http://visionmedia.github.com/mocha/)).

I'm used to working on Node or PHP applications, in which I would normally just specify the libraries I need as npm dependencies. I don't know what the "Rails way" is here.

I'd like to know whether there's a defacto standard, and what tools you use in your Rails applications to lint/test your front-end code. If it still makes the most sense for me to use Node for this stuff (adding a package.json for deps and a JS tool like [Jake](https://github.com/mde/jake)), then that's fine.

Comment: Rails 3 addresses some of this but Rails has had test frameworks for testing UI since the beginning.  I cannot emphasize enough that getting off Rails 2 is a worthy an important point and ease your transition.  But it sounds like you might want to read up on Rails.  It uses a different approach than Node or PHP.  And while it's possible to continue coding your front-end in JS, you'll end up replicating (in a different language) a fair amount of functionality that Rails does already.  Porting to Rails 3 will be a great exercise to help you learn its strengths and weaknesses.

Comment: @tharrison I'm sure you're right, I agree it's a good idea to stay up to date but it's a little out of my remit – I'm mostly a front-end developer and my knowledge of Ruby is quite lacking :) I will bring this up with our ruby guys but not sure where it'll get me

Comment: Another approach you might want to consider, if you're all about JSON and JS, would be to use the Rails part as more of a JSON API (this functionality pretty much comes for free with Rails).  In one recent instance, we built an app that was based on Backbone.JS to handle the front end, and used Rails to handle all the back-end stuff.  You can do this either as a true RESTful API, but it's probably easier to keep it all in one app.  There are a number of gems that help integrate Backbone.JS or your front-end framework of choice with Rails.  It's gonna suck until you get to Rails 3, though! :-)